# Запуск JARа скомпилированного из проекта Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar

Разработал проект *Maven* в *NetBeans*.
Пытаюсь его запустить с *JAR*-ника командой

> java -cp MyProject-0.1.0.jar ru.com.myproject.Main

где

> ru.com.myproject.Main

есть главный класс, потому несмотря на то что я указал главный класс в
 *Свойства проекта > Выполнить > Главный класс*
он все равно не указывается в манифесте...

Получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thetransactioncompany/jsonrpc2/JSONRPC2Parser
        at ru.com.myproject.<clinit>(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2Parser
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 1 more
```

Содержимое файла *pom*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonrpc2-base</artifactId>
            <version>1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Так как же собрать проект *Maven* в *NetBeans* так что бы правильно был настроен *manifest*-файл: был правильно прописан главный класс и зависимости ?

Или как вообще запустить собранный проект *Maven* ?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Это практически то что нужно - *manifest*-файл сгенерировался с главным классом и указанием зависимостей! Ара! Есть какая-то возможность из автоматически складывать рядом с скомпилированным *JAR*-ником?

Comment: Нашел решение на Хабре - https://habrahabr.ru/post/131164/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java не может найти зависимости, в частности jsonrpc2. Можно либо добавить их jar-файлы в CLASSPATH, либо упаковать в один jar. Первое можно сделать как вручную, так и с помощью `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Второе с помощью `maven-assembly-plugin`:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: Вот меня и интересует как это сделать? Ведь в Maven проектах manifest-файл нет - он генерируется... Как его настроить я не понимаю?